# WPF Update List binded on DataGrid from other Thread & Class

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, binding, datagrid

ANSWER :

```
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { logs.Add(this); }));
```

I try to create a log system for my server (Log.cs)

I made this class log:

```
public class Log
{
    public enum Flags
    {
        [Description("SERVER - OK")]
        OK,
        [Description("SERVER - ERROR")]
        ERROR
    }


    public string EtatLog { get; set; }
    public string MessageLog { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Log> logs = new ObservableCollection<Log>();

    public Log(Flags flag, string message)
    {
        EtatLog = GetEnumDescription(flag);
        MessageLog = message;

        logs.Add(this);
    }

    private string GetEnumDescription(Enum enumValue)
    {
        var fieldInfo = enumValue.GetType().GetField(enumValue.ToString());

        var descriptionAttributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        return descriptionAttributes.Length > 0 ? descriptionAttributes[0].Description : enumValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

I have binded my ObservableCollection on my Datagrid like that :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GridLogs" Margin="0,5,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:FieldModifier="public">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EtatLog}" Header="ID du Logs"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MessageLog}" Header="Message du Logs" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now this is my problem : I want to create a server, so I use many thread to run it (like my Login Listener). If I have a new connection (user) i want to write a log in my list, so i do this :
Log log = new Log(Log.Flags.OK, "New co...");

But, I use multi threading, so my datagrid cannot update because it run on the primary thread...

I have this error (in French):

[image]

How can I resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to allow the main UI thread to add to the collection.

Use Dispatcher for that

```
public Log(Flags flag, string message)
{
    EtatLog = GetEnumDescription(flag);
    MessageLog = message;
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => {
        logs.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use "this" because it's "log.cs" class, not my Mainwindows :/
My error : Dispatcher dosent exist...

Comment: Can you use "Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()" ?

Comment: God it work :)
Thx dude !

  Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                logs.Add(this);
            }));